# Black Lion Audio Mods?

Tags: converter, mbox, pro-tools, modification

I'm going to upgrade from my original Mbox 2 to an Mbox 3 soon. I was browsing around the internet for a bunch of stuff when I stumbled upon this.

http://www.blacklionaudio.com/content.php?p=47

I wanted to know if anyone around here has had any work done with them and if it was really worth getting the upgraded components in this set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the MBox mods, but I have used their 192 I/Os before and they sound extremely better than the stock DigiDesign I/Os I own before I modded them..

And I tested their new 192s against the "Avid" ones,

and guess what:

Looks like Avid put the same I/O circuitry in the "new" 192 I/Os that they had in their 003s...

Black Lion's sound 10X better.

I would suggest getting a demo unit before you commit to anything, but I highly recommend them.

And, I know a mixer who was approached by Avid saying "We'll give you brand new 192 I/Os for free in your mixroom if you say you use them in a magazine article" and the answer was an 
emphatic NO. And, he uses Black Lions exclusively on his line.

But, as always, try it for yourself and take no-one's word except your own to determine if you like it or not.